# Reload page fails after changing state with $state.transitionTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

In my angular controller, I have part of the code

```
$state.transitionTo('newState', {}, { notify: false })
  .then(function () {
    $window.location.reload();
  });
```

Reason for this is that I need to reload the page due some server-side rendering and then go to **newState**
This works fine in Chrome and IE, but in FireFox it reloads the page but stays in the same state. Is this some known issue with FireFox, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ui-router supports this functionality already:

```
$state.go('newState', {}, { notify: false, reload: true });
```

It's better to use `$state.go` rather than $`state.transitionTo` in virtually all cases, fyi.

Comment: I tried your solution, but it doesn't work in any of the browsers.